# CSS image-background of child element showing above image-border

Tags: html, css, background, background-image, border

I have the following markup:

```
<div id="carousel-is-sl-for-me" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-is-sl-for-me" data-slide-to="0" class="active">
    <li data-target="#carousel-is-sl-for-me" data-slide-to="1">
    <li data-target="#carousel-is-sl-for-me" data-slide-to="2">
    <li data-target="#carousel-is-sl-for-me" data-slide-to="3">
    <li data-target="#carousel-is-sl-for-me" data-slide-to="4">
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

    <div class="item active" style="background-image: url('<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/image/carousel-placeholder-01.jpg');">

      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">

            <div class="panel panel-info">
              <div class="panel-heading">1 in 4 people</div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                <p>...text goes here</p>

                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>
                  Download PDF
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-is-sl-for-me" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-is-sl-for-me" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Notice how `.item` has a background applied to it as an inline style.

Then, in my CSS I have the following CSS border:

```
#carousel-is-sl-for-me {
  border-image-slice: 15 27 15 27;
  border-image-width: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  border-image-repeat: repeat repeat;
  border-image-source: url('../image/marker-border-image-white-big-reversed.png');
  border-style: solid;
}
```

However, the image background of the `.item` is hiding the image border of `#carousel-is-sl-for-me`:
[image]

Seeing as `#carousel-is-sl-for-me` is the parent element, I would have thought it's image borders would have been on top? Here is how they should look (if I hide the image background):
[image]

Is there an easy way to get around this?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], so that people can easily test this/experiment with it.

Comment: The `background-img` of `#carousel-is-sl-for-me` is hidden below `.item` because `.item` sits on top of `#carousel-is-sl-for-me` - `.item` occupies the full width and height of `#carousel-is-sl-for-me` so any background property declared on `#carousel-is-sl-for-me` will not be visible. Try adding a margin around `.item` or declare a `max-width` and `max-height` - whichever works best; the objective should be to reduce enough space around `.item` to reveal some background detail of `#carousel-is-sl-for-me`

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError thanks, I've just tried adding a margin and can see now that it reveals the border image beneath... unfortunately I can't really use that as a workaround however, as the border image has an uneven / rough edge that needs to overlap the image, rather than a straight line that can sit next to it (if that makes sense)

Comment: @pealo86 might be beter to add a screenshot or wireframe of the intended end result.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError the screengrabs in my original post shows how it looks along with how I'd like it to look

Comment: No, it doesn't demonstrate the complete intended result (both background images combined) - if your second screenshot was your intended end result then you wouldn't be here now since you would already know how to accomplish that ("if I hide the image background"). At this stage I still don't know how you expect these elements to appear with both background images appearing (`background-image` of `.item` with `background-image` of parent element). In any event, it sounds like you need to declare the `background-image` style rule to an element nested within `.item` or a sibling of `.item`

Comment: Or explore a combination of both background images in one style rule declared on one element; e.g: `background-image: url(/path-to-image), url(/path-to-image)`. The best solution may be to declare the `background-image` of `.item` for `#carousel-is-sl-for-me` instead, and the `background-image` of `#carousel-is-sl-for-me` for `.item`. Otherwise, try to set the `background-image` for `#carousel-is-sl-for-me` to a sibling element (which you might have to add in) of `.item` that appears after and higher in the stack order